# Where I can select from which field I want to calculate Work Details

Tags: azure-devops

could you tell me please where and how to setup Work Details.

We have introduced a new mandatory field called Remaining Work1. We want that Work Details would calculate the numbers from these fields. At the moment Work Details show the total numbers from Remaining Work field that we have hidden.

So could you tell me please where I can select from which field I want to calculate Work Details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Inherited process (default) does not support that. If you use Azure DevOps Server XML process (previous model), you can try to use [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=azure-devops-2020) and update [Agile tool fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020#assign-agile-tool-fields).